# Can't log with hardcoded crypted password with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with hardcoded crypted password to correctly login into my app with FOSuserBundle.

Here the original encrypted password by FOSUserBundle :

```
    if ($encoder instanceof BCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        $user->setSalt(null);
    } else {
        $salt = rtrim(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(random_bytes(32))), '=');
        $user->setSalt($salt);
    }

    $hashedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, $user->getSalt());
    $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
    $user->eraseCredentials();
```

Here mine :

```
 $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);

        $salt = rtrim(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(random_bytes(32))), '=');
        $user->setSalt($salt);

        $hashedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($request->get('plainPassword'), $user->getSalt());
        $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($user);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

When I loggout, I can't login with the actual new created password...

I don't know how it's work..

Does anyone have a idea ?

Thx by advance

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: I use Symfony 3

Comment: Where is this code used? Can you show us some context? Does the password change in the database? What encoder are you getting back from `$this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user)`?